# How do fly fishing lures work?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle, fly-fishing

I'm new to fishing and I don't know how these things work. Do I need to add some weight to make them sink or fishes will come at the top to bite them?

I've seen some videos where they use some weight and some of them just start fishing with the lures, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fly fishing, there are two types of flies, wet and dry.

The wet flies are designed to sink and bitten by the fish underwater, while the dry lures are designed to sit on top and the fish will come up and bite them. If you are really lucky the fish will leap out of the water to do so.

The short version of how they work is to you cast them out and then gently reel them back in on still water (ponds and such) or cast them upstream on flowing water and the reel as they come back down the stream to you.

You don't need to add weight, just switch to the other type of fly if you would rather fish below the surface.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd just like to mention that often the wet flies have a bead or weighted tape wrapped around the hook shank to make them sink.  The dry flies are often made out of animal hair or foam so they float.  There is also fly line made to either sink or float for wet or dry flies respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Dry fly**

Designed to imitate aquatic or terrestrial insects floating on the surface of the river. Generally dry flies are cast upstream and allowed to drift back with the current.

The cool thing with dry fly fishing is that you usually see the trout eat your fly off the surface

**Nymph**
Generally designed to imitate the small insect larvae that live on the bottom of the river. Nymphs are generally cast upstream and allowed to drift back with the current.

Nymphs often have weight built into them with lead or beads to help them sink to the bottom of the river.

**Streamer**

Generally imitating baitfish.

Can be cast out and retrieved or cast across the river and allowed to swing downstream.

Streamers can be either weighted or unweighted. A floating or sinking line can be used.