# Would dry or wet flies be easier for a beginner fly fisherman?

Tags: fly-fishing

Inspired by this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20031/how-do-lures-work), if someone was just starting out fly fishing, would dry flies (float on top of the water) or wet flies (sink below) be easier for a beginner to use?

My experience is that wet flies are easier, but it has been a while, and I haven't showed a new person in a long time.

Would wet or dry flies be easier for someone just learning how to fly fish?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fly fishing technique to swing a wet fly, nymph, or streamer cast downstream. All you need to do is to cast downstream and let the current take your line until the fly sinks and comes up again due to the line tension. Eventually you will need to learn to mend to control speed and depth, but it is nothing compared to the amount of line control and mending that one has to do when fishing with dries.

Comment: Fishing streamers at a stream mouth can be very easy as you can feed line out into the current if you can't cast far enough.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking the target species, season and location into account as the deciding factors.

I started with wet flies because I was targeting bass and panfish in a small inland lake during the summer.  The lake was just a convenient place to fish and a muddler minnow was productive.

If your convenient place is a nearby trout stream in the spring when the midges are emerging, then go with a dry fly.

If you just want to learn how to cast, then tie a piece of yarn on the end of your line and go to an open field; no water is necessary.  I am currently using this method in my back yard with my baitcasting setup.  Though, I'm using a lure with no hooks on the line instead of yarn.